# generating random numbers with C language

Tags: c, random

I am trying to printf a bounce of natural numbers (from 0 up to 10) using srand but when I run the code, it generate numbers with 7 digit.
How is it possible? Can anybody tell me where I am doing wrong?

```
enter code here

#include <stdio.h>    
#include <stdlib.h>    
#include <time.h>    

#define DIMA 10
#define DIMB 2

int main()
{
    int A[DIMA], B[DIMB], i, j, flag;
    srand (time(NULL));

    for (i=0; i< DIMA; i++);{
        A[i]=rand() % 11;
    }

    for (i=0; i< DIMB; i++);{
        B[i]=rand() % 11;
    }

    for (i=0; i<DIMA; i++){
        printf("%d ", A[i]);
    }

    printf("\n\n");
    for (i=0; i<DIMB; i++){
        printf("%d ", B[i]);
    }
 return 0;
}
```

Thanks for support.

Comment: Don't put semicolons before your loop bodies.

Comment: Just in case the other comment isn't clear enough, you have `for (i=0; i< DIMA; i++);{` and the semicolon between `)` and `{` is wrong — it is the empty body for the loop and the statement block is executed once after the loop completes.

Comment: And note the error becomes obvious if you defer declaration of variables until you need them. If you declare `i` in the loop, it's not in scope when the stray semicolons are present and the compiler emits an error.

Comment: Thank you very much to all for your super quick reply and sorry if my question is off-topic.

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
for (i=0; i< DIMA; i++);{
```

to

```
for (i=0; i< DIMA; i++) {
```

Note the extra semicolon `;` before `{`, same for the second loop.

Comment: thank you very much to all for your super quick reply and sorry if my question is off of topics.